# Pandas: Add column to DataFrame based on Series values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I performed a `groupby` which gives me a `pd.Series` object. Something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
spanish = pd.Series(['uno', 'dos', 'tres'], ['one', 'two', 'three'])
>>> spanish
    one       uno
    two       dos
    three    tres
    dtype: object
```

I have my original `pd.DataFrame` containing one column who's indices match with the `pd.Series`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'german': ['eins', 'zwei', 'drei'],
                   'english': ['one', 'two', 'three']},
                  index=[1, 2, 3])
>>> df
      german english
    1   eins     one
    2   zwei     two
    3   drei   three
```

As can be seen above, the `english` column matches with the indices from the `spanish` series. I now want to add the `spanish` values to `df`. In other words, I want to get this:

```py
>>> df
      german english spanish
    1   eins     one     uno
    2   zwei     two     dos
    3   drei   three    tres
```

**Note**: I tried to use `loc` to assign `spanish[df['english'][i]]` when iterating, but this process is extremely slow (my real `DataFrame` has around 6 million entries). Furthermore, I can't use `groupby.transform()` because I'm grouping on another `DataFrame`. Lastly, I can't use indices (0, 1, 2) because they don't match either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest use `map` like `df['spanish'] = df['english'].map(spanish)`

Comment: Perfect! That was a lot easier than I thought. Thanks